# Linking the checkbox to the code. Progress bar for Pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, pyside6, pyqt6

Tell me, there is a code, it opens, reads, changes a file (I can enter any number and a new column with data will be created) and save. Sometimes, a column is not needed. So I made a checkbox. However, when you click on the button, the 3rd field remains, which, in fact, should be deleted. How to fix? And the second question, how to implement a progressbar for pandas? So that the code understands that the process of processing the file has begun, and when it ended.

```
import os
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
import pandas as pd

class WinConvSmuNtu(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('В СМУ/НТУ')
        self.cwd = os.getcwd()
        self.setFixedSize(280, 150)

        # btn1
        self.btn_of = QPushButton('Open', self)
        self.btn_of.setFixedSize(100, 30)
        self.btn_of.move(10, 10)
        self.btn_of.clicked.connect(self.clk_btn_of)

        # combobox
        self.combo_sep = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_sep.addItems([',', ';', '.', ':', ' '])
        self.combo_sep.setFixedSize(30, 30)
        self.combo_sep.move(125, 10)
        self.combo_sep.currentTextChanged.connect(self.set_sep) 

        # btn2
        self.btn_sf = QPushButton('Save as', self)
        self.btn_sf.move(170, 10)
        self.btn_sf.setFixedSize(100, 30)
        self.btn_sf.clicked.connect(self.slot_btn_sf) 

        self.input_data = QLineEdit('num', self)
        self.input_data.move(10, 50)
        self.input_data.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(-1000.00, 1000.00, 3))
        self.input_data.textEdited.connect(self.znql)  

        self.chb_b = QCheckBox('Delete Z', self)
        self.chb_b.move(130, 50)
        self.chb_b.setFixedSize(120, 30)
        self.chb_b.stateChanged.connect(self.st_chekbox)

        # btn3
        self.btn_run = QPushButton('Run', self)
        self.btn_run.move(75, 85)
        self.btn_run.setFixedSize(100, 20)
        self.btn_run.clicked.connect(self.run_script)  

        # progressbar
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.move(10, 120)
        self.pbar.setFixedSize(240, 20)
        # self.thread.signal_thr.connect(self.signal_accept)

    def set_sep(self, _):
        self.vs = self.combo_sep.currentText()
        return self.vs

    def clk_btn_of(self):
        self.filename_choose, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                                                         "OpenFiles",
                                                         self.cwd,  
                                                         "Text Files (*.txt);;PTS Files (*.pts)")
        self.path = self.filename_choose
        return self.path

    def slot_btn_sf(self):
        self.file_sv, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,
                                                      "SaveFiles",
                                                      self.filename_choose,  
                                                      "Text Files (*.txt)")

    def znql(self, double):
        self.znach_qlineedit = float(double)

    def st_chekbox(self, state):
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            self.df = self.df.drop(['Z'], axis=1)
            print(self.df)
        else:
            self.df

    def run_script(self, state):
        self.files_import = pd.read_csv(self.path, sep=self.vs, names=["X", "Y", "Z"])  
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.files_import)
        self.df['SMU'] = round(self.df['Z'] + self.znach_qlineedit, 2)  
        self.save_file_smu = self.df.to_csv(self.file_sv, sep=',', index=False, header=False)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = WinConvSmuNtu()
window.show()
app.setStyle('Fusion') 
app.exec()
```

Comment: Does that column actually exist? Is the new dataframe printed correctly? (Note: I strongly suggest you to use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)).

Comment: This part of the code `self.df['SMU'] = round(self.df['Z'] + self.znach_qlineedit, 2)  
        self.save_file_smu = self.df.to_csv(self.file_sv, sep=',', index=False, header=False)` writes 4 columns to the file. The checkbox, if clicked, does not work. If it worked, then only 3 columns should remain in the file

Comment: I didn't ask what your code does, please read more carefully my question.

Comment: Yes, there are 3 columns in the source file. And yes, the code creates the 4th column with the changed values from the 3rd column. But, how to edit the code so that when the checkbox is clicked, column 3 is not displayed, but 4 remains, with new values

Comment: Add `if self.chb_b.isChecked():` `self.df = self.df.drop(['Z'], axis=1)` *before* `to_csv`. Note that the general logic of the program has many issues. For instance, if you toggle the checkbox more than once (or toggle before creating the dataframe), it will crash. You should: 1. always check if the dataframe exists; 2. do not continuously open and create a new dataframe in `run_script` (that was the source of your problem); 3. only set `filename_choose` and `file_sv` if the value returned by the file dialog exists; 4. remove all those returns, as they are useless when connected to a signal.

Comment: Thank you! 3 and 4 points done. Yes, indeed, they are not needed. Regarding point 2, I did not quite understand how to implement it